# How to Port to Linux Interprocess Event with AutoResetEvent from Windows

Tags: linux, windows, events, inter-process-communicat

My current Windows code uses a named event for inter-process communication. There can be many processes waiting on the event, when it's signaled, all the waiting processes are released and then the event returns to a non-signaled state. I use the PulseEvent function for this.

How do I do this in Linux? The pthread functions seem to be inter-thread communication. I don't see where semaphores can provide the same behavior as Windows has. The Posix semaphore seems to only release one waiting thread. If the semaphore could release all waiting threads then that would work. Is there something in Linux I'm missing?

Comment: Did you consider using some portable library like Qt ??

Comment: I don't see where it supports the functionality I need.

Comment: Depending on what exactly you want to do, maybe a condition variable (`pthread_cond_init()/pthread_cond_wait()/pthread_cond_broadcast()/pthread_cond_destroy()`) or a barrier (`pthread_barrier_init()/pthread_barrier_wait()/pthread_barrier_destroy()`) may be appropriate.

Comment: Auto reset events are tough in Linux, and I've never seen one. I have seen manual events, and a nice equivalent appears to be [pevents](https://github.com/NeoSmart/PEvents).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a futex can provide the behavior of the Windows event.